# Why there is no AndAttribute in specflow?

Tags: java, .net, cucumber, bdd, specflow

When i generate a step definition with And/But attribute it takes the previous steps attribute(Given/When/Then). I feel the implementation in cucumber is better as we can use And/But as it is and its more aligned with bdd.

Why there is no separate 'And'/ 'But' Attribute, is there a significant reason not using in Specflow?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about a programming issue but a design decision, and this is not the place to ask that sort of stuff

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually `And` and `But` are just syntactic sugar for the actual step type of `Given` `When` or `Then`. All steps are really of one of those types. In the specflow implementation it would be possible to have different implementations for `And` steps which were after a `Given` and those after a `When`, where as in a language where `And` is a native step type this wouldn't be possible. Conversely you have to attribute an `And` step with two attributes to use it both after a `Given` and a `When`.

This might be a good thing or might be a bad thing. In the end I think this is just an implementation decision which is swings and roundabouts, and make little difference.